# Difficulty Saving Image To MemoryStream

Tags: c#, image, stream

I'm having some difficulty saving a stream of bytes from an image (in this case, a jpg) to a `System.IO.MemoryStream` object.  The goal is to save the `System.Drawing.Image` to a `MemoryStream`, and then use the `MemoryStream` to write the image to an array of bytes (I ultimately need to insert it into a database).  However, inspecting the variable `data` after the `MemoryStream` is closed shows that all of the bytes are zero...  I'm pretty stumped and not sure where I'm doing wrong...

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(filename))
{
    byte[] data;

    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
        data = new byte[m.Length];
        m.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    // Inspecting data here shows the array to be filled with zeros...
}
```

Any insights will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To load data from a stream into an array, you *read*, not *write* (and you would need to rewind). But, more simply in this case, `ToArray()`:

```
using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
    data = m.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Cool, I've always misunderstood read and write concerning streams up until this point.  Thanks!

Comment: This won't work for all image types. Such as `tiff` images fail on the `.Save()` call

Answer (score 4):

If the purpose is to save the image bytes to a database, you could simply do:

```
byte[] imgData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"path/to/image.extension");
```

And then plug in your database logic to save the bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually just using a file on my local pc to isolate the problem that I was having.  In the application I'm using, the image is actually coming in as an array of bytes.  I'm trying to instantiate an Image class to do some processing before saving it to a database.  Good to know about ReadAllBytes!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found for another reason this article some seconds ago, maybe you will find it useful:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ImageConverter.aspx

Basically I don't understand why you try to write an empty array over a memory stream that has an image. Is that your way to clean the image?

If that's not the case, read what you have written in your memorystream with ToArray method and assign it to your byte array

And that's all

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'm actually trying to do some processing on an image uploaded on a website before saving it to a database.  I guess the System.Drawing.Image namespace has some functionality for resizing, so I was using the Image class.

Comment: Yea definitely good idea. That's the right place where you should search. Care about performance, Image class can easily consume a lot of memory (that's what making me mad in my current project)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, it works for me

```
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
                panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.Bounds);
                bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] Pic_arr = new byte[ms.Length];
                ms.Position = 0;
                ms.Read(Pic_arr, 0, Pic_arr.Length);
                ms.Close();
```

Well instead of a Image control, I used a Panel Control.